# Need to open a userform with combobox lists but with values already selected

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I have a userform that works fine. Now I need to edit some values I selected using the userform,so I want to open the userform with the values already selected. I already have the userform that saves the values in some sheets, I try to open the same userform but with the values I already selected selected when I open the userform.

How can I do it? This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Worksheets("Info").Activate

    With Worksheets("Info").Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(ComboBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then

            Dim cliente As String
            Dim prov As String
            Dim dia As Integer
            Dim mes As String
            Dim año As Long
            Dim prod As String
            Dim fob As Long
            Dim hon As Variant
            Dim fee As Variant
            Dim cont As Integer
            Dim est As Integer
            cliente = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
           prov = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
           dia = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
           mes = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
           año = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
           prod = c.Offset(0, 6).Value
           fob = c.Offset(0, 7).Value
           hon = c.Offset(0, 8).Value
           fee = c.Offset(0, 9).Value
           cont = c.Offset(0, 10).Value
           est = c.Offset(0, 21).Value
           '
       End If
   End With
   'HERE STARTS THE PROBLEM!!!
   ' Now I open the userform, I need comboboxs open with the old values           
   UserForm1.Show
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = cliente
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = prov
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = dia
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = mes
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = año
   UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = prod
   UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = fob
   UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = hon
   UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = fee
   UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = cont
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = est

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserForm1.Show` defaults to modal, so you need to set its properties before you show the form.  What the code currently does is show the form, then after the form exits, creates a **new** UserForm1 (the old one had already been unloaded), sets its properties, then allows it to go out of scope.  Try this:

```
Dim form_one As UserForm1

Set form_one = New UserForm1
temp.Controls("ComboBox1").Value = cliente
'etc...
form_one.Show
```

If I understand the workflow correctly, the simpler solution might be to `.Hide` the form after the user selects everything instead of unloading it.

Comment: dear @comintern I tried what you coded, the problem now is that it gives me "error 424" and object is needed

Answer (score 0):

For adding Items to your `ComboBox` use below syntax:

```
ComboBox1.AddItem "your value"
```

like this:

```
UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem = cliente
```

---

For showing a default item use its index:

```
UserForm1.ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2
```

If you have only its text use a loop:

```
For i = 1 To ComboBox1.ListCount
    If (ComboBox1.List(i) = myValue) Then
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I know how to do that, I need to open an spececific value when I open the userform, greetings.

Comment: @diego you want to show a default selected item, If yes so I edit the answer ;).

Comment: @ shA.t , Yes I want to show a default item wich I only have its text. I tried what yo wrote but its doesnt work =(, If you could edit my hole code with what you gave me it would be awesome.